# When a user visits www.mysite.com/string can it redirect to my index and use that string?

Tags: php, string, .htaccess

Currently I have it setup like this so when a user visits www.mysite.com/test.php?u=String the user string will be set as String.

```
$user = $_GET['u'];
```

But is it possible to have it if a user searches www.mysite.com/String it would set the user value as the string.

```
$user
```

I’m guessing it would require me to edit the .htmlaccess file but I am unsure on how I would do this.

Thankyou in advance

Comment: you can get it by JavaScript and send it to your PHP file !!

Comment: Common thing to do is always go through an `index.php` and then in `.htaccess` have that removed from the url. You can then do whatever you want with the params. FYI this is called routing and there is a lot to it. Might want to look into some frameworks if it is a big project.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a .htaccess redirect for all requests, and route them to your test.php file, which then assigns the string to your $user variable.

The script would look something like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test.php?u=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

I hope you're also considering the security risks of letting a user input any string they want in your script just by visiting mysite.com/String

Answer (score 0):

It's [.htaccess](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) not *.htmlaccess*

If you want to keep the URL as something like:
`http://www.example.com/search` but, in reality, direct to `http://www.example.com/test.php?u=search` then you'll probably want a [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

In this instance, to route **everything** that's neither a file nor a directory to *test.php?u=string*

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test.php?u=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

`http://www.example.com/this/is/not/a/directory` will be routed to `http://www.example.com/test/php?u=this/is/not/a/directory`

This needs to be in an .htaccess file at your document root.